# Button to dynamically clone a form field

Tags: javascript, beginner, form, django

I am very new to javascript and started with a very basic add button to my django app. Everything I found was using jQuery but for only one small script jQuery seems to be a too big overhead for me. Everything is working but I want to get some suggestions regarding coding style:

```
function hasReachedMaxNum(type) {
    var total = parseInt(document.querySelector("#" + type + "-TOTAL_FORMS").value);
    var max = parseInt(document.querySelector("#" + type + "-MAX_NUM_FORMS").value);
    return total >= max
}

function cloneMore(element, type) {
    var total = parseInt(document.querySelector("#" + type + "-TOTAL_FORMS").value);
    newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
    for (var input of newElement.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
        input.name = input.name.replace("-" + (total - 1) + "-", "-" + total + "-");
        input.id = input.name;
        input.value = null;
    }
    for (var label of newElement.getElementsByTagName("label")) {
        var forElement = label.getAttribute("for");
        forElement = forElement.replace("-" + (total - 1) + "-", "-" + total + "-");
        label.setAttribute("for", forElement)
    }
    total += 1;
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
    document.querySelector("#" + type + "-TOTAL_FORMS").value = total;
    return newElement
}
var addChoice = document.getElementById("add-choice");
addChoice.onclick = function() {
    var choices = document.getElementById("choices");
    cloneMore(choices.lastElementChild, "choice_set");
    if (hasReachedMaxNum("choice_set")) {
        this.disabled = true
    }
};
```

Just for reference the html looks like this:

```
<ul id="choices">
  <li>
    <label for="choice_set-0-choice_text">Choice:
    </label>
    <input id="choice_set-0-choice_text" maxlength="200" name="choice_set-0-choice_text" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="choice_set-1-choice_text">Choice:
    </label>
    <input id="choice_set-1-choice_text" maxlength="200" name="choice_set-1-choice_text" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="choice_set-2-choice_text">Choice:
    </label>
    <input id="choice_set-2-choice_text" maxlength="200" name="choice_set-2-choice_text" type="text" />
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
  <button type="button" id="add-choice">Add another choice
  </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Could you give a expliantion for the down vote? What is wrong with the post?

Comment: It would be better if you make a live snippet here. `TOTAL_FORMS` and `MAX_NUM_FORMS` are missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the answers and work with the limitations of django the html now looks like this:

```
<form id="create" method="post" action="/create/">
  <input name="choice_set-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="5" />
  <input name="choice_set-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" />
  <input name="choice_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="choice_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="20" />
  <ul id="choices">
    <li>
      <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-0-choice_text" type="text" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-1-choice_text" type="text" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-2-choice_text" type="text" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-3-choice_text" type="text" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-4-choice_text" type="text" />
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <button type="button" id="add-choice">Add another choice
    </button>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

And the script like this:

```
function $(selector, element) {
    if (!element) {
        element = document
    }
    return element.querySelector(selector)
}

function $$(selector, element) {
    if (!element) {
        element = document
    }
    return element.querySelectorAll(selector)
}

function hasReachedMaxNum(type, form) {
    var total = parseInt(form.elements[type + "-TOTAL_FORMS"].value);
    var max = parseInt(form.elements[type + "-MAX_NUM_FORMS"].value);
    return total >= max
}

function cloneMore(element, type, form) {
    var totalElement = form.elements[type + "-TOTAL_FORMS"];
    total = parseInt(totalElement.value);
    newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
    for (var input of $$("input", newElement)) {
        input.name = input.name.replace("-" + (total - 1) + "-", "-" + total + "-");
        input.value = null
    }
    total++;
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
    totalElement.value = total;
    return newElement
}
var addChoiceButton = $("#add-choice");
addChoiceButton.onclick = function() {
    var choices = $("#choices");
    var createForm = $("#create");
    cloneMore(choices.lastElementChild, "choice_set", createForm);
    if (hasReachedMaxNum("choice_set", createForm)) {
        this.disabled = true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery suits beginners well. If you insist on original dom programming, try to define some shorthands to avoid original verbose methods.

```
function $(selector){
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

function find(element,selector){
    return element.querySelector(selector);
}
function findAll(element,selector){
    return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Or if you know [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

function find(element,selector){
    return element.querySelector(selector);
}
function findAll(element,selector){
    return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Chrome also use some of these [shorthands](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector) in console.

With these shorthands, you can shorten your code:

From

```
var choices = document.getElementById("choices");
```

To

```
var choices = $("#choices");
```

---

From

```
newElement.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

To

```
findAll(newElement,"input")
```

Comment: The code really looks cleaner now but I get a TypeError:Illegal invocation  on the line which uses the document.querySelector shortcut.

Comment: @R3turnz OMG... It's my fault, sorry for this. I updated my code.

Comment: Thanks but I found a better solution, which uses [just two functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/QuerySelector).

Comment: @R3turnz  cool :D

Comment: @R3turnz  BTW, dom programming sucks. If you think jQuery is too long for this, try [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com)

Comment: I know and I will start using jQuery for a bigger project. But I designed the complete site without javascript and for this small script in my opinion it didn't changed much in terms of readability and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with your HTML. As there are some problems in the way you are forming it that is making your javascript more complex than it has to be.  I would like for you to consider an `<li>` definition that looks like this:

```
<li class="choice">
    <label>Choice:
        <input maxlength="200" name="choice_set[]" type="text" />
    </label>
</li>
```

For the `<input>` element's `name` property, I have changed it to use array access notation.  This will allow most server-side languages to automatically populate a numerically-indexed array with all values populated into it.  This moves you away from the whole paradigm of naming things like `choice_set-*` (both `name`s and `id`s).  Because of this, I have done away with the `id` property for the `<input>` as it really serves no purpose when using this approach other than to require you to add a bunch of logic to make these values unique.  I have also nested the `<input>` inside it's `<label>` to connect the two, since we don't have id to ties things together anymore. Finally, I have added a class to the `<li>` as a means to provide a way to query against these elements in DOM (could obviously be used for styling as well).

This would greatly simplify your cloning operation to something like:

```
var addChoiceButton = document.getElementById('add-choice');
// set 'choices' element to variable so you don't need to re-query DOM
var choices = document.getElementById('choices');
// select first choice LI to use as template so you don;t need to re-query DOM
var choiceTemplate = document.getElementsByClass('choice')[0];
addChoiceButton.onClick = function() {
    var newChoice = choiceTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    var input = newChoice.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    input.value = '';
    choices.appendChild(newChoice);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Do your `*_FORMS` values really need to be stored in hidden input fields?  What is the value of doing this versus injecting these values right into javascript variables?  They can't hold any value for server-side validation, as a user could easily modify these so why make it so painful to extract these configuration settings from a DOM element as opposed to just:

```
var maxChoices = {{ [dynamic value from server] }};
```

It certainly makes no sense to increment your counters an input fields at all.  You could probably reduce all your javascript to something like:

```
var maxChoices = {{ [dynamic value from server] }};
var addChoiceButton = document.getElementById('add-choice');
var choices = document.getElementById('choices');
var choiceTemplate = document.getElementsByClass('choice')[0];
addChoiceButton.onClick = function() {
    if(choices.childElementCount < maxChoices) {
        var newChoice = choiceTemplate.cloneNode(true);
        var input = newChoice.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        input.value = '';
        choices.appendChild(newChoice);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using django and it seems that I can not customize this behaviour. I can remove the id's but than I have to identify the inputs by name. This should not be a problem because they must be unique.

Comment: @R3turnz I do not believe it is correct that input name values must be unique in Django. A quick search revealed this example for how to access data from form fields  using array notation for `name` property - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318639/trouble-accessing-html-array-input-field-values-in-django-server-side

Comment: @R3turnz Please see my updated answer, where I have provided some more information based on having read your answer on the page.

Comment: In your linked question the user manipulates the behavior of django forms. For example all helper methods generate the form like I posted them. I don't know why but the [managment form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) (TOTAL_FORMS etc.) is also required.

Comment: Also note that the user does not even use the forms framework and the first comment on the question: _Drop the [] notation. That's from PHP or Rails and is unnecessary._